# How to setup slimerjs in console on Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, xulrunner, slimerjs

I am trying to make screenshot of webgl models with slimer.js from console

1. I install dependencies

   # sudo apt-get install libc6 libstdc++6 libgcc1 libgtk2.0-0 libasound2 libxrender1
2. I download package for Linux x86_64 from http://slimerjs.org/download.html
3. Install firefox

   # apt-get install firefox
4. create script

   var system = require('system'),
       page = require('webpage').create();

   page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
     page.render('test.png');
     phantom.exit();
   });
   page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
     console.log(msg);
   }
5. add path to firefox.app

   # export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox
6. run slimer with xulrunner

   # ./slimerjs/xulrunner/xulrunner ./slimerjs/slimerjs screen.js
7. And finally get error:

> # ./slimerjs/xulrunner/xulrunner ./slimerjs/slimerjs screen.js
>
> (process:23815): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion
>   'sys_page_size == 0' failed Error: App:Name not specified in
>   application.ini

What I am doing wrong?
Help me, please, to find out.

With all best regards. Anton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was in firefox version

> # python slimerjs.py --debug=true ../screen.js    (process:24063): GLib-CRITICAL : g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0'
>   failed Error: Platform version '31.0' is not compatible with 
>   **minVersion >= 17.0.0 maxVersion <= 29.**